# uwp cursor hide when media is playing

Tags: uwp, cursor, media, nullreferenceexception, uwp-xaml

I am trying to hide the mouse pointer after a few seconds when media starts playing. So far I have tried the following which should do this job but a null reference exception is thrown sadly.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
```

> project min target : creators update
>
> target : Fall creators update.
>
> control used for media : mediaplayerelement.

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have tried the following which should do this job but a null reference exception is thrown sadly.

The problem is you have not invoked this method in UI thread. Please try to set `PointerCursor` as `null` like the follow.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you the way I used to hide/unhide the mouse cursor:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved += CoreWindow_PointerMoved;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
```

```
private async void CoreWindow_PointerMoved(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
{
    if (Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor == null)
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
    Stopwatch.Restart();
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    if (Stopwatch == null) return;
    if (Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1500)
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
}
```

In this code, I added a global StopWatch property

`Stopwatch Stopwatch { get; set; } = new Stopwatch();`

You should handle somewhere to dispose of the Stopwatch and unregister the events like OnNavigatedFrom

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved -= CoreWindow_PointerMoved;
Stopwatch.Stop();
Stopwatch = null;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 0);
AppCore.Instance.MediaPlayer.Pause();
Frame.GoBack();
NavigationManager.BackRequested -= NavigationManager_BackRequested;
NavigationManager.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
NavigationManager = null;
```